# Google Analytics & Ajax: is it sure / right using this syntax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-analytics

I'm using a ajax-driven contact form. Is this the right syntax to use for sending a Universal Analytics event?

```
[...]    
success : function(response) {
    $('#ajaxresponse').html(response);
    ga('send', 'event', 'getting_info', 'sending_email');
```

I'm using new GA Universal Code and in Setup Goals i've used this syntax:

[image]

Comment: Are you seeing the event come through real-time reports? Syntax appears to be right.

Comment: No at the moment... I moved dates to today:i can see the visits but my goals are 0...  Maybe i can see only from tomorrow?

Comment: Today I can see the goals registered. So, this is the right way. @Blexy thank you for your confirm in first place!

Comment: Right! Sorry @Blexy! Just done!